# Prevent Duplicated user entries - Django

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a crud operation that corresponds to multiple users. Whenever I hit the update function, a new entry is being added without modifying the existing one. Can someone help me out with this?

**models.py**

```
class Employee(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="employee",null=True,blank=True)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     contact = models.CharField(max_length=15)
     designation = models.ForeignKey(Designation,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def employee_form(request,id=0):
if request.method == 'GET':
    if id == 0:       
        # req = request.user.designation 
        form = EmployeeForm(request)
    else:

        employee = Employee.objects.get(pk=id)
        if employee in request.user.employee.all():
            form = EmployeeForm(request,instance=employee)
        else:
            return redirect('/emp')
    return render(request,'employee-form.html',{'form':form})
else:
    if id==0:
        form = EmployeeForm(request,request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            print("Im passed")
            name = form.cleaned_data["name"]
            contact = form.cleaned_data["contact"]
            designation = form.cleaned_data["designation"]
            t = Employee(name=name,contact=contact,designation=designation)

            t.save()
            request.user.employee.add(t)
    else:

        employee = Employee.objects.get(pk=id)
        if employee in request.user.employee.all():
            form = EmployeeForm(request,request.POST,instance=employee)

            if form.is_valid():
                print("Im passed")
                name = form.cleaned_data["name"]
                contact = form.cleaned_data["contact"]
                designation = form.cleaned_data["designation"]
                t = Employee(name=name,contact=contact,designation=designation)

                t.save()

                request.user.employee.add(t)

    return redirect('/emp')
```

I pretty much understand it's creating a new entry because of **request.user.employee.add()**
I've tried making it update(), It threw an error update() has only 1 positional argument.

Comment: Can you please add your `User` & `Employee` model ?

Comment: Can u check now?

Comment: I have post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you have to first get the Employee with the logged-in user, then update all the detail of Employee and save that object...

```
employee_obj = Employee.objects.get(user=request.user)

employee_obj.name = name
employee_obj.contact = contact
employee_obj.designation = designation
employee_obj.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've tried set, but it says 
TypeError
'Employee' object is not iterable

Comment: You want to update the employee's details which are connected with logged in user.
And all those details you got from the form, right?

Comment: That's exactly what I need!

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: if form.is_valid():
                    print("Im passed")
                    name = form.cleaned_data["name"]
                    contact = form.cleaned_data["contact"]
                    designation = form.cleaned_data["designation"]
                    
                    employee_obj = Employee.object.get(user=request.user)

                    employee_obj.name = name
                    employee_obj.contact = contact
                    employee_obj.designation = designation
                    employee_obj.save()

error:
type object 'Employee' has no attribute 'object'

Comment: If I use save(), The entry just vanishes from the list.

Comment: Oops, its typo its not `object`. it is `objects`, just update in my answer too.

Comment: Yeah Great, Happy Coding :)